# Numpy failing in subtraction even after same dimensions of arrays

Tags: numpy

When I subtract these two arrays, it returns a (354,354) shaped array because as per the documentation there is a mismatch in the shape of the arrays.
Why does it happen and what else can I do for this except `numpy.reshape` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that I have also run into before, right now your ytrain is a one dimensional array (advisable to avoid). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694829/10733051) answer.

expanding(adding) additional dimension while assigning **ytrain** should fix your problem

```py
x = np.array([1, 2])
x.shape
(2,)
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
y
array([[1],
       [2]])
y.shape
(2, 1)
```